# How to convert 160 digit binary string to 20 byte array?

Tags: java

I have a binary string containing 160 digit.
I have tried:

```
new BigInteger("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000001000000000010000011010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 2).toByteArray()
```

but it returns the 15 bytes array with removed leading 0 bytes.

I would like reserve those leading 0 bytes, keep it 20 bytes.

I know some other ways to accomplish that, but I would like to know is there any easier way might just need few lines of code.

Comment: You can extend your array by `8-currentSize` elements with value = 0 on the left side

Comment: Provide example of `binStr` and expected output?

Comment: @anubhava It's implied by OP's line of code: `binStr = "0011010111...11"; array = {120, -145, ..., 20}`.

Comment: You still can't store 160 bits in 8 bytes - you need 20 bytes.

Comment: You could use System.arraycopy to copy to copy to 8 byte array

Comment: 8 bytes only hold 64 bits, as @Ingo said you need 20 bytes for 160 bits.

Comment: Here is the binStr
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000001000000000010000011010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
public static byte[] convert160bitsToBytes(String binStr) {
    byte[] a = new BigInteger(binStr, 2).toByteArray();
    byte[] b = new byte[20];
    int i = 20 - a.length;
    int j = 0;
    if (i < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("string was too long");
    for (; j < a.length; j++,i++) {
        b[i] = a[j];
    }
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this code should work for you:

```
byte[] src = new BigInteger(binStr, 2).toByteArray();
byte[] dest = new byte[(binStr.length()+7)/8]; // 20 bytes long for String of 160 length
System.arraycopy(src, 0, dest, 20 - src.length, src.length);
// testing
System.out.printf("Bytes: %d:%s%n", dest.length, Arrays.toString(dest));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Bytes: 20:[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 65, -96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```